# Database connection to Neo4j with Pentaho Spoon

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, pentaho, kettle

I want to connect to Neo4j with Pentaho Kettle Spoon. I downloaded jdbc driver of neo4j with [this](https://github.com/rickardoberg/neo4j-jdbc) and I tried to use [this guide](http://irregular-bi.tumblr.com/post/25430299054/neo4j-data-integration-with-pentaho-kettle) to connect to neo4j with Pentaho Kettle Spoon.
I have two main problems:

1. downloaded JDBC Driver is zip file.
   I changed Driver extension to jar for solving this problem.
2. when I changed extension to jar and copy it in lib folder and follow [this guide](http://irregular-bi.tumblr.com/post/25430299054/neo4j-data-integration-with-pentaho-kettle) I faced missing driver error:

> org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver could not be found

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: it gives the source you need to add the jar file to spoon doesn't it?

Comment: yes, it is. I need to add Neo4j JDBC to spoon.

Comment: How did you change it to jar?

Comment: I changed it with rename!!

Comment: I dont think it will work like that you need to compile it

Comment: what is the best way to change it? I don't have enough experience with java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not rename the .zip file you downloaded from Github and add to lib folder. You need to compile the source code and add the .jar file to it.
Or you can download the already compiled file from [here](http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-jdbc/neo4j-jdbc-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and add to the `data-integration\lib` folder and restart the spoon.

In `Table Input` step select

- Connection type as `Generic database`
- Custom connection URL
  as  `jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474`
- Custom driver class name as `org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I put a connector for Neo4j on the PDI Marketplace, which adds "Neo4j" to the list of database sources so you don't have to configure a Generic Driver or download the driver from Neo4j.