# Migrating from SQL server to Neo4j with Pentaho Kettle Spoon

Tags: sql-server, neo4j, pentaho, kettle

I want to Migrate from SQL Server to Neo4j. I used CSV for this mean but I need to a ETL Tool for solving this problem with simplest way.
for this reason I use Pentahoo Kettle Spoon.
I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052354/database-connection-to-neo4j-with-pentaho-spoon) to connect to Neo4j with Pentaho Kettle Spoon.
How can I migrate from SQL Server to Neo4j with Pentaho Kettle Spoon?
Which Tools can help me in Pentaho Kettle Spoon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced to this problem and I could solve it. :)
At first you need to add `Table Input` tool for getting records from SQL Server then you can add `Execute SQL Script` from `Scripting` tool.
 create your `Transformation` from `Table input` to `Execute SQL Script`. then Get fields and check mark :

- Execute for each row?
- Execute as a single Statement

then you can add your Cypehr Query Like that:

```
CREATE(NodeName:NodeLabel{field1:?,field2:?,field3:?,...})
```

Execute Transformation and Enjoy it! :)
**--------------------------------------------------------

Edited:**

Load CSV Command in Neo4j is very faster than Create All Nodes node by node. you can use Load CSV advantages in Pentaho Kettle Spoon. for this mean we need two `Transformation`s, first Transformation exports Data to CSV and second Transformation loads CSV to Neo4j.
For First Transformation:
add a `Table Input` and a `Text File Output` to transformation. Config Connection String and other parts of them.
For Config Neo4j Connection String, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052354/database-connection-to-neo4j-with-pentaho-spoon)
For Second Transformation:
add a Execute SQL Script tool to transformation, Config Connection String and Write below code for that:

```
 LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///C:/test.CSC' AS Line
 CREATE(NodeName:NodeLabel{field1:Line[0],field2:Line[1],field3:Line[2],...})
```

at final create a job and add the transformations to that.

Comment: Doesn't neo have some native bulk load tools? The above must be pretty slow? I'd have thought it would be quicker to extract with pdi, write to a suitable file that works for the bulk tool then call that?

Comment: before this solution I extracted Data from MS SQL Server and then I used Load CSV for load data to Neo4j. I want to Compare this two solutions in the next week for bulk loading and I can say true answer for your question after testing.

Comment: I tested both solutions. Load CSV is 3 times faster.